# Hide window on process.start with user and password

Tags: c#, process, process.start, windows-task-scheduler

I have the following code inserted in a console application:

```
Process delete = new Process();
startInfo.FileName = "schtasks.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\";
startInfo.UserName = @"AdminUser";
startInfo.Domain = @"mydomain";
startInfo.Password = encryptedPassword;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.Arguments = @" /delete /s 192.168.1.5 /tn Task1 /F";
delete.StartInfo = startInfo;
delete.Start();
delete.WaitForExit();
delete.Close();
```

This code runs fine, but a new window is launched. I understand that it happens because I run the process with explicit username and password but I really need this and I also need to hide the window, is there a possibility to do that?
As an alternative, I need to execute "schtasks" as an administrator of the remote machine without using the parameters /U and /P of schtasks because I need to encrypt them, so afaik the only possibility is to use Securestring (as I do in my code).
Can you help me?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved by setting the [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle) to `Hidden`:

```
startInfo.WindoStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: Clarification: this code is part of a console application, so there is already a window opened (and should stay opened til the end), while the second window launched by the delete.Start should stay hidden.